# SyntaxError : Unexepected token 'export'

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So yeah I'll just get to the point, an error gets thrown at me, while I don't know what to do, it's quite weird because the code is fine there is just something wrong with what I'm saying here.
Here is where the problem is:

```
const { codeBlock } = require("@discordjs/builders");
const { ExplicitContentFilterLevels } = require("discord.js/typings/enums.d.ts");

async function clean(client, text) {
  if (text && text.container.name == "Promise")
    text = await text;
  if (typeof text !== "string")
    text = require("util").inspect(text, {depth: 1});

  text = text
    .replace(/`/g, "`" + String.fromCharCode(8023))
    .replace(/@/g, "@" + String.fromCharCode(8023));

  text = text.replaceAll(client.token, "[REDACTED]");

  return text;
}

exports.run = async (client, message, args, level) => {
  const code = args.join(" ");
  const evaled = eval(code);
  const cleaned = await clean(client, evaled);
  message.channel.send(codeBlock("js", cleaned));
};

exports.conf = {
  enabled: true,
  guildOnly: false,
  aliases: [],
  permLevel: "Bot Owner"
};

exports.help = {
  name: "eval",
  category: "System",
  description: "Evaluates arbitrary javascript.",
  usage: "eval [...code]"
};
```

here is where the error gets thrown at me:

```
ERROR Unhandled rejection: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export' 
C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\Tap\node_modules\discord.js\typings\enums.d.ts:4
export const enum ActivityTypes {
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
    at Object.compileFunction (node:vm:352:18)
    at wrapSafe (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1031:15)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1065:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1153:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:94:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\emilb\OneDrive\Desktop\Tap\commands\eval.js:2:41)
```

Comment: You can't import from a Typescript file when your project is Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't import from a Typescript (.ts) file when your project is Javascript. (Not to mention you shouldn't import from .d.ts files anyway.)

Since you're not using `ExplicitContentFilterLevels`, just remove the line attempting to import it.

Comment: Now I know that!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are not supposed to import a `*.d.ts` file. Those files are TypeScript definition files, which are there to help you IDE offer better type hints.

Change the import to this:

```js
const { ExplicitContentFilterLevels } = require("discord.js/src/util/Constants");
```

Or even better change it to the line below, because that way you are not tied to the internal structure of the Discord package.

```js
const { Constants: { ExplicitContentFilterLevels } } = require('discord.js');
```

Comment: Thank's that works!

Comment: @Emiluvik Glad to help!